# Why is my subnet data source returning a VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using a module my coworker wrote, but for some reason, I am getting subnet not found -- and the identifier begins with `vpc-`. Why is this returning a VPC and not a subnet?

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "app" {
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.default.id}"

  tags = {
    SubnetType = "app"
  }
}
```

Which is being passed through to the module as

`private_subnets     = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.app.*.id}"`

and used here:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "default-alb" {
  name                 = "${chomp(data.template_file.standard_name.rendered)}"
  launch_configuration = tostring(element(aws_launch_configuration.default,count.index).name)
  min_size             = "${var.min_instances}"
  max_size             = "${var.min_instances}"

  target_group_arns = [
    tostring(element(aws_alb_target_group.default-http,count.index).arn),
  ]

  vpc_zone_identifier = var.private_subnets

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: Error creating AutoScaling Group: ValidationError: The subnet ID 'vpc-004[redacted]' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: 73e98545-975c-11e9-bd63-fd4915ceeabf

  on .terraform/modules/core-api/alb.tf line 1, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "default-alb":
   1: resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "default-alb" {
```

Shouldn't the subnet identifier begin with `subnet-`?

Comment: Are you sure that's how you're passing it in to the module? The `aws_subnet_ids` doesn't have an `id` argument or attribute so Terraform should throw an exception there. Also you don't appear to be using a `count` on that so don't need the splat operator you have there. In general I'd expect that to be `data.aws_subnet_ids.ids` instead of what you're showing.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I am definitely sure that's how I'm passing it, since I copied and pasted, but i'm not sure it's correct lol. It should be multiple IDs for multiple subnets found. Maybe that's the issue; I will play with that and see

Comment: That's not how that data source is used. If you were looping over multiple `aws_subnet` data sources with a `count` then yeah that would work like that but instead you're using the `aws_subnet_ids` data source which should be accessed as mentioned in the last comment.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR if you make that an answer I'll accept it, that was the problem. I got overzealous converting to 0.12 and lost track of how different data source is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aws_subnet_ids` data source doesn't have an `id` argument or attribute so Terraform should throw an exception there and I'm a little surprised it isn't doing so.

Also you don't appear to be using a count on that so don't need the splat operator you have there.

So instead of:

```
private_subnets = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.app.*.id}"
```

You should be using the `ids` attribute to return a list of all the subnet IDs that match your filter:

```
private_subnets = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.app.ids}"
```